# Converting float image to 8bit using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, convert, import

I am working with Google Earth Engine. I would need to convert a float image to an 8-bit image.

As stated on https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization, "it is possible to use the image.visualize() method to convert an image into an 8-bit image for display or export".

However, when trying to do it with an uploaded asset (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/m_perrone/L8qm_PC1), this method isn't working.

Do you have any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code line:

```
var image8b = image.unitScale(-3, 3).multiply(255).toByte();
```

Be sure to select the appropriate unit scale. I have used (-3, 3) because I don’t really know the value range that is interesting in your file.