# Rescale NDVI [-1,1] to 0-255 using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I need to rescale the NDVI values [-1, 1] into [0, 255] in order to compute GLCM textures in Google Earth Engine (JS-API). I'm able to compute the NDVI of my imagery using as follows:

```
// load image
var img = ee.Image('users/my_user/IMG')

// plot image
var imgViz = {bands: ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], min: 0, max: 255};
Map.addLayer(img, imgViz, 'True color composite');

// compute NDVI
var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['b1', 'b2']);

// plot NDVI
var ndviViz = {min: -0.5, max: 0.5, palette: ['green', 'white', 'red']};
Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviViz, 'NDVI')
```

Note that *red = b1* and *nir = b4*.

However, when I apply `.int8()` obtain 0 values in all pixels.

```
// compute NDVI (0:255)
var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['b1', 'b2']).int8();

// plot NDVI
var ndviViz = {min: 0, max: 255, palette: ['green', 'white', 'red']};
Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviViz, 'NDVI')
```

How can I rescale the NDVI where -1 is 0 and 1 is 255?

Comment: Hi! This was answered yesterday: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/418472/converting-float-image-to-8bit-using-gee
So in your case it would be: `img.normalizedDifference(['b1', 'b2']).unitScale(-1, 1).multiply(255).toByte();`

Comment: @aldo_tapia Thank you!